# A matrix with purely imaginary eigenvalues is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is it true that if A is a matrix with only eigenvalues that are purely imaginary, then is it invertible?

Comment: Well, invertibility for a square matrix means that $0$ is not an eigenvalue.

Comment: $0i$ is purely imaginary?

Comment: $0$ is also purely imaginary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it isn't since

**Theorem:** Over *any* field, a square matrix is invertible iff its determinant is not zero iff zero is *not* one of its eigenvalues.

Now, since the real part of $\;0\in\Bbb C\;$ vanishes we get that zero is a purely imaginary number, so...

Answer (score 3):

The following fact is useful for an $n\times n$ matrix $A$

> if $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_n$ are eigenvalues of $A$, then $|A|=\lambda_1\lambda_2\dots\lambda_n $.